# Deploying site on IIS server throws 404 on saving stylesheet for umbraco rest services

Tags: c#, iis, http-status-code-404, umbraco7

Im trying to redeploy my Umbraco site on an IIS server. All seems to be working fine on the site's front end however on the backoffice I'm having a problem. Suddenly saving stylesheets on the IIS server site is throwing a 404.

How I tried to redeploy the Umbraco site:

I redeployed my site by just copy pasting the files from the old non IIS server to the new IIS one.
Have tried to republish my local copy from the visual studio, still throws the same error.
Is this a problem on the settings of that server or the umbraco site? I'm really lost here. Im using umbraco 7.10

See screenshots below (First one is from the IIS server, second is from the non IIS server with no problems) console log/network when firing the rest service.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xGXD.png]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add images rather as images than as links. This time I've done this for you - please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Comment: Are you deploying your Umbraco application in IIS as a separate root level website or just as an application under IIS website? A screenshot of IIS Manager will be helpful